# Mutation Observer is triggered even when attribute value do not change

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

When I change an attribute value with the same value, looking at the inspector console, the DOM tree does not change, yet Mutation Observer triggers since I modified the attribute value, but for the actual same value.

Can someone explains how this works under the hood? I inserted a snippet to demonstrate my point.

```js
/* OBSERVER */
var divToUpdate = document.querySelector('#update');
var config = {attributeFilter: ['data-update']};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.target.dataset.update == 'true') {
      console.log('Attribute value updated, but not really!', mutation);
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(divToUpdate, config);

/* BUTTON UPDATER */
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
 divToUpdate.setAttribute('data-update', true);
});
```

```html
<div id="update" data-update="true">DIV WITH ATTRIBUTE</div>
<button type="button">UPDATE DIV ATTRIBUTE</button>
```

Comment: `divToUpdate.setAttribute('data-update', true)` and `divToUpdate.setAttribute('data-update', 'true')` both triggers the mutation observer in my testing. Or I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I reproduced your results, but if I change the attribute and the value being set to `a` or `truex`, it doesn't trigger. There's something specific about `true`.

Comment: @mplungjan and @Barmar could you share a jsfiddle to show? Because with my testings, whether its `true`, `"true"` or `"abc"` it does not make any difference. The answer from @Rob_M seems to confirm what I thought but Iet's see if someone comes up with a full explanation.

Comment: My mistake, I did not see the =='true' tested too. the click will trigger regardless of the value changing or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to this history, MutationObserver was designed to work that way. Any call to setAttribute triggers a mutation, regardless of whether the value is being changed or set to the current value. https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/520#issuecomment-336574796

Comment: Try OPs code but swap “true” and true for “a” and it does not trigger